# Regex search pair of parenthesis at different lines in python

Tags: python, regex

This is the example string in a file I work with:

```
apple (sweet
   fruit) at home
```

If I want to find anything between parenthesis and remove it, how to do it?
This is the result that I expect for:

```
apple at home
```

I tried below but it doesn't work as above lines are two different lines.

```
re.sub(r'\(\s*([^)]+)\)', '', line)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
re.sub(r'\s*\([^)]+\)', '', line)
```

In a python regex, `(` and `)` are normally used for grouping.  Because you want to match literal parens, not do grouping, we replace `(` by `\(` and we replace `)` by `\)`.

Example:

```
>>> print(line)
apple (sweet

      fruit) at home
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\s*\([^)]+\)', '', line)
'apple at home'
```

#### Issues with reading a multiline string from a file

Using the `read` method, we can successfully do the multiline substitution:

```
>>> import re
>>> line = open('File').read()
>>> print(line)
apple (sweet
   fruit) at home

>>> re.sub(r'\s*\([^)]+\)', '', line)
'apple at home\n'
```

If we use the `readlines` methods, though, we have problems:

```
>>> line = open('File').readlines()
>>> print(line)
['apple (sweet\n', '   fruit) at home\n']
```

`readlines` creates a list of lines.  `re.sub` requires a string not a list.  Therefore, we need to use `join` to get a successful substitution:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\s*\([^)]+\)', '', ''.join(line))
'apple at home\n'
```

Comment: Thanks John1024, but it doesn't work on my PyCharm. It works with one line parenthesis pair but not with multiple lines. I think it's correct because the input is each line. So somebody may help me to figure out processing multiple lines.

Comment: @braun Hmm.  I don't have PyCharm but I have tried this under Python2 and Python3 and it works for me.  Can try this at the python prompt and see if it works for you?  If it does, then we know it is a pycharm issue and not a python issue.

Comment: @braun here is an example of it working: https://repl.it/CfTw it works on multiple lines by default. I'm guessing you don't have a multiline string, you have a list of three separate strings, right? What is `type(line)` ? `str` or `list` (or `tuple`)? If it's not `str`, then try `line2 = '\n'.join(line)` then use the regex on that.

Comment: @braun Following up on TessellatingHeckler's insightful comment, the question states that you have this _"example string in a file_".  So, a key question is: how are you reading in the file?  If you use `.read()`, you will get a multiline string.  If you use `.readlines()`, you will get a list of lines which is a completely different animal.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use re.MULTILINE and non-greedy match.

```
re.sub(r'\(.+?\)', '', line, re.MULTILINE)
```

Reference:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: This doesn't work: https://repl.it/CfTy  as per the documentation, `re.MULTILINE` option only changes what the special characters `^` and `$` match.

Comment: Looks like a simple iteration rather than regex would solve the problem, and solve it more efficiently.

Comment: Hi Wai Leong, could you advise how to use a "iteration" you said? I tried all solutions here but not worked. I think it's because fileinput works differently with regex tester.

Comment: @braun you should try John1024's solution if you insist on regex. What I said was not a regex solution. Simply just running a for loop over the string and pick up '(' and ')', which is easy to do while going over line by line (iterating) in files.